# Find the matching row in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my Table

```
Id   | No   |Group
1    | 1    |Alpha
1    | 1,2  |Alpha
1    | 2,4,5|Alpha
```

How can i find the the row which has `No` as `5` using laravel eloquent

```
$Match = MyModel::whereIn('No', array(5))->get();
```

But it didn't return any rows.

When i try to see the query executed it shows me

```
select * from `table` where `No` in (5)
```

How can i do this in php and laravel

Comment: You really should normalize your database, because searching for comma-separated values in a table will always be a painful exercise, and never efficient because the database can only ever do a full table scan and never use indexes when searching for that data

Comment: If you really absolutely have to do this, then use Laravel's [DBRaw](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) with MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

Comment: Ah, I should do it.. Can't do it in eloquent ? If so can you tell me how to do it in find_in_set

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462)

Comment: Probably a bad idea, but you could use LIKE if they're all under 10.

Comment: It's not an issue with Eloquent.... Eloquent simply assumes that your database is sensibly designed, it doesn't provide any special tools that can automagically make a badly designed database look like a well designed database

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes i agree. Can you help me in laravel's dbraw with mysql's findinset ?

Comment: Why can't you normalize the data properly? That's the correct solution to your problem.... using FIND_IN_SET() is really just a hacky workround for an unnormalized database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a pure Eloquent workround, you might be able to do something like:

```
$id = 5
$Match = MyModel::with(array('No' => function($query) use($id) {
   $query->where_id($id);
}))->get();
```

Using Raw and FIND_IN_SET, something like:

```
$Match = MyModel::whereRaw(
    'find_in_set(?, `No`)',
    [5]
)->get();
```

(Untested)

But this will never be an efficient query because it can't use indexes; and there are many other reasons why a comma-separated list is a bad idea (such as lack of referential integrity)

The real solution will always be to normalize your database properly